# Uploading an Image from React Native to Loopback API with Fetch

Tags: android, react-native, loopbackjs

Hello This is my first time trying to build an API. What I am trying to do is send an image saved on my phone through react-native to a loopback container that would save the image on my computer. I'm having trouble formatting the form data correctly so the image will be accepted by loopback. I've been trying:

```
let photo = {names: 'file', uri:'file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20161028_094032.jpg'}
let formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append(photo.names, photo.uri)

fetch('http://192.168.0.15:3000/api/containers/container2/upload',{
method: 'POST',
body: formdata
}).then(response => {
}).catch(err => {
})
```

The response I get back is:

```
_bodyText: '{"result":{"files":{},"fields":{"file":["file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20161028_094032.jpg"]}}}' }
```

Which is incorrect because the file should be in "files" and not "fields"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `xhr` instead of `fetch`. This is the [example provided by Facebook](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Network/FormData.js#L28) for this scenario...

```
// Polyfill for XMLHttpRequest2 FormData API, allowing multipart POST requests with 
// mixed data (string, native files) to be submitted via XMLHttpRequest.

var photo = {
  uri: uriFromCameraRoll,
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  name: 'photo.jpg',
};

var body = new FormData();
body.append('authToken', 'secret');
body.append('photo', photo);
body.append('title', 'A beautiful photo!');

xhr.open('POST', serverURL);
xhr.send(body);
```

Comment: Awesome! glad to have helped.